# Fast search in multiple strings

Tags: java, android, string, search, realm

I've been struggling with a task for a while now..
I have 3 different string fields (company name, stock name (like "utp cable 3x2.5"), barcode (don't ask why but the company stores barcodes in strings and doesn't want to change it)) and I must compare them to a string which is given in the search bar.
I currently use a simple String.contains with OR connection between them, but it's very slow.
It's like 30 seconds to iterate trough 2000 elements but it's way different on faster devices(2 secs).
I've also tried to execute the same query using realm but it wasn't much different.
Another solution was to concatenate the 3 strings into one, then run the query but it seemed slower than the original.
I need an algorithm or a library which is suitable for my needs. Can you suggest me any please?

Comment: Did you tried to tag your search items?

Comment: Have you considered posting code so that people can actually see what you are currently doing?

Comment: @HarisQureshi what do you mean by that?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce sure i can but it's just three string.contains with OR connection between them.

Comment: which db are u using

Comment: Realm, but I do not iterate the `RealmResults` and don't know why you are.